# Listener for Orientation: Portrait and Landscape?

Tags: java, android, listener

I've an app which calculate the subnettable.
But if I change the orientation the TextViews are empty.

I search for an listener for this. Alternatives are welcome to :D
In the listener I'd recalc the table.

Comment: alternative: you could just set your activity as portrait-only or landscape-only

Comment: thx - but I think on tablets its bad to use it only on landscape... ;)

Comment: @rala what is `subnettabel`?

Comment: you wanted alternatives and you got some ;-) @rala

Comment: yes thx, but say also what they do -> sry table :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in you activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration myConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(myConfig);
    int orient = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
    switch(orient) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            // handle landscape here
            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            // handle portrait here
            break;
        default:
        }
}
```

Comment: onConfigurationChanged() should be called automatically in an activity, no need to setup a listener.

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29). I just noticed that you also need to set the configChanges attribute in your AndroidManifest (see link).

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest > activity tag add:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.activity.name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This will prevent your activity from getting recreated when you rotate or change your orientation and hence you wont get blank TextView (will retain your previous value)

Comment: android:name="at.ralaweb.ralaprogramme.subnetztabelle.ActivityMain" android:label="@string/title" android:configChanges="orientation" >  
doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry about that, also include screenSize in configChanges. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use OrientationEventListener:

```
orientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation)
    {
        //do something
    }
};
```